# Acceder a JSON obtenido mediante AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un problema, por más que le busco no encuentro como puedo acceder al array que obtuve después de haber hecho una consulta mediante AJX con PHP y enviado el resultado en formato JSON a javascript. Espero me puedan ayudar, de plano no entiendo como por mas tutoriales que he visto. Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda">                              
            </div>
            <div id="datos">              
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
                  
    </body>
</html>
```

```
function buscar_datos(consulta)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buscar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {consulta: consulta}
    })


            .done(function (respuesta) {

//Aquí no encuentro la forma de recuperar la matriz de datos que envíe desde PHP en formato JSON.

            });

}



$(document).on('keydown', '#caja_busqueda', function () {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    buscar_datos(valor);
});
```

Mi PHP

```
<?php

$buscar = str_replace(" ", "%", $_POST['consulta']);

if ($buscar != "") {

    $mysqli = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "bd_secjo");
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

    $query = "SELECT Id_Contacto, Nombres, Apellido_Paterno, Apellido_Materno FROM bd_secjo.contactos where concat(nombres, ' ', apellido_paterno, ' ', apellido_materno) like '%" . $buscar . "%' limit 10;";

    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

    $ArrayDatos = ObtenerArraySQL($resultado);
    echo json_encode($ArrayDatos);

    $mysqli->close();
}

function ObtenerArraySQL($SQL) {

    $rawdata = array();
    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL)) {
        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: y que error te arroja este codigo ?

Comment: Ninguno, el problema es cómo acceder a los datos JSON, generalmente me va a devolver una matriz bidimensional de Id, nombre, apellidos, pero no encuentro la forma de acceder a dichos datos desde JavaScript

Comment: muestrame desde js como llega la estructura de datos, aunque creo que el error es la forma en la que envias los datos

Comment: has un `echo $ArrayDatos ` para ver si te esta agregando los arrays, cosa que no creo

Comment: Me lleva, me faltaba el return en mi función ObtenerArraySQL, llevo tres horas con ese problema.

Comment: si, exactamente por eso, ys te funciono ? @Carlos Daniel Zárate Ramérez

Comment: Ya me funcionó. Muchas gracias. Con razón siempre me marcaba null al momento de querer recuperar el JSON. Vaya error más simple.

Comment: Si aveces esos pequeños errores nos detienen un resto, por eso le pregunte eso.... exitos bro

Comment: Muchas gracias bro. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

en el metodo done del ajax se recive te dejo metodos logs para poder ver posibles errores

```
done(function (respuesta) {
    // console.log(respuesta);
    json=$.parseJSON(respuesta);
    // console.log(respuesta);
 });
```